# Avraham Adon shel Sarah?

Tags: commentaries, vayera, abraham, sarah

Why does Sarah refers to Avraham as אדני Adoni ([Genesis 18:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#12))? Why not say Ishi אישי or Ba'ali בעלי if she is refering to him as her husband? Why would she call him her master/lord?

Comment: Are אישי or בעלי used ever in Tanakh? If not then this is likely just the accepted word for husband at the time.

Comment: @DoubleAA Devarim 22:22? Bereshit 29:32, 34? Found some more verses which are clearly about a husband sending his wife away. So I do believe these terms are used at the time

Comment: Use for land owner: וְהֵ֖ם בַּעֲלֵ֥י בְרִית־אַבְרָֽם
 -- 
בראשית 14:13
  also 49:23